# Hot Network Questions and "Your Communities" show incorrect site icons

Tags: bug

Here on my communities, it shows Personal Finance & Money with the Movies & TV site icon (which I'm also a member of) and the Sci Fi & Fantasy sites with the Information Security icon (which I'm also a member of).

I'm not sure where the Mathematics or Literature icons came from, but those aren't right either.

[image]

Here on the Hot Network questions, a question on the Skeptics SE site is shown with the Software Engineering SE icon, and a question on the Personal Finances SE site is again shown with the Movies & TV logo:

[image]

Out of curiosity, has anyone else been seeing this kind of behavior?